# Javascript - passing by value in a loop

Tags: javascript

I have the following code inside a class:

```
this.buttons = {
        cancelButton:{buttonId: "cancelButton", buttonText:"Cancel", buttonClick: function(){alert('Cancel');}},
        confirmButton:{buttonId: "confirmButton", buttonText:"Ok", buttonClick: function(){alert('Ok');}}};
}
for(var button in buttons){
    var buttonId = buttons[button].buttonId;
    var buttonClick = buttons[button].buttonClick;
    var buttonText = buttons[button].buttonText;
    $("#confirmDialogWrapper #buttons").append('<button type="button" id="'+buttonId+'" class="button_neutral"><div class="btn_black"><div class="btn_black_inner">'+buttonText+'</div></div></button>');
    $("#confirmDialogWrapper #"+buttonId).click(function(){
        buttonClick();
        $("#popup_background").fadeOut(200);
        $("#confirmDialogWrapper").remove();
        delete this;
    });
```

My problem is that each button gets the "buttonClick function" of the final iteration element. In the above example each button will alert "Ok" - which is not ok :)
However the buttonText value is correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another function to create a new scope:

```
for(var button in buttons){
    (function(button)
    {    
        var buttonId = buttons[button].buttonId;
        var buttonClick = buttons[button].buttonClick;
        var buttonText = buttons[button].buttonText;
        $("#confirmDialogWrapper #buttons").append('<button type="button" id="'+buttonId+'" class="button_neutral"><div class="btn_black"><div class="btn_black_inner">'+buttonText+'</div></div></button>');
        $("#confirmDialogWrapper #"+buttonId).click(function(){
            buttonClick();
            $("#popup_background").fadeOut(200);
            $("#confirmDialogWrapper").remove();
            delete this;
        });
    })(button);
}
```

Comment: `delete this`, wtf??? remove it please (http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)